# Atom Editor Plugin: Can I create a dialog box?

Tags: javascript, plugins, dialog, atom-editor

I am writing an Atom plugin, but I want to check a few options with the user.

The plugin has submenus for different tasks. Each task will want a few options to be set.

For that I would like to present a dialog box with the sort of form controls you use in HTML forms, such as check boxes, radio buttons and text boxes. I would want a different dialog box for each submenu item.

Atom Editor doesn’t seem to make much use of them, so I’m not even sure it can be done.

How can I create or emulate a dialog box?

Comment: Why not use a standard Atom notification with a button that opens the package settings?

Comment: @idleberg Thanks for your comment. Can you explain how to do that? I have also edited the question to make clear what I wanted. It’s not just one set of preferences.

Comment: Do you want a dialog box, or do you want what you described?

Answer (score 4):

The Atom API offers several dialogs, including [confirm](https://atom.io/docs/api/latest/AtomEnvironment#instance-confirm), [modal](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.13.1/Workspace#instance-addModalPanel) and [notifications](https://atom.io/docs/api/latest/NotificationManager). Unless you want to code your own modal with its own logic, you could make use of notifications to communicate that your package requires its settings to be adjusted.

**Example:**

```
var meta, notification;

meta = require("../package.json");

if (atom.config.get(meta.name + ".essentialSetting") === false) {
  notification = atom.notifications.addWarning("You need to adjust your package settings", {
    dismissable: true,
    buttons: [
      {
        text: "Open Settings",
        onDidClick: function() {
          atom.workspace.open("atom://config/packages/" + meta.name);
          return notification.dismiss();
        }
      }
    ]
  });
}
```

Opinionated: If you decide to put this in `activate()`, it *might* be a good idea to make this less obtrusive by adding a second button:

```
{
  text: 'Ignore',
  onDidClick: function () {
    atom.config.set(meta.name + '.muteWarning', true);
    notification.dismiss();
  }
}
```

PS: You can ignore the `meta.name` bit and replace it with the name of your setting, it's something I'm using in most of my packages for convenience.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but, since I want to check settings frequently, I think I would rather pursue the __modal__ option. The link you provided was eye-opening, but it’s not very informative. Do you know where I can learn more about this?

Comment: The Atom API documentation is rather brief. Maybe take a look at the source of the  [script](https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script) package. Its [dialog](https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script/blob/master/lib/script-options-view.js) for the `script:run-options` command is a relatively complex modal.